# Upper bound of the analytic rank of the modular Jacobian varieties $J_1(N)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, modular-forms

Does there exist an upper bound of the analytic rank of the modular Jacobian varieties $J_1(N)$?
(Or more generally of $J_\Gamma$ for a congruence subgroup $\Gamma_0 \subseteq \Gamma \subseteq \Gamma_1$.)
I want one like $ rank J_1(N) < C \dim J_1(N)$, for some nice small constant $C$.
($N$ is an arbitrary positive integer, or it’s ok to assume that it is a prime number)

I know there’s such upper bound for $J_0(p)$ and for $C$ smaller than $1.2$.

(See Kowalski, E., Michel, P., The analytic rank of  J 0 ( q )  and zeros of automorphic  L -functions, theorem 1,
and Kowalski, E., Michel, P., VanderKam, J. M., Nonvanishing of higher derivatives of
automorphic L-function.)

Can we generalize them?
I am not familiar with the analytic number theory, the symmetric square of modular forms, and every analytic things mentioned in the papers at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember discussing this with Emmanuel Kowalski not long ago. The short answer is that generalising the result to $J_1(N)$ is an open problem, and seems to be very difficult.

Comment: What about $N$ squarefree ?

Comment: Even the case of $J_1(p)$ for $p$ prime is hard.